# Как изменить механизм открытия вкладок?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, вкладки

Доброго всем времени! Есть скрипт вкладок, которые открываются путем нажатия на ссылки, например `<a href="#content1">`. Как можно изменить механизм открытия вкладок, чтобы в html ссылки

```
<a href="#content1">Вкладка 1</a>
<a href="#content2">Вкладка 2</a>
<a href="#content3">Вкладка 3</a>
```

заменить на блоки с `id` или атрибут `data-id`

```
<div id="#content1">Вкладка 1</div>
<div id="#content2">Вкладка 1</div>
<div id="#content3">Вкладка 1</div>
```

Благодарю за помощь!

```js
$(".social_icons>a").click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
    $(".social_icons>a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");

    $(".social_container>div").hide();
    t_content = $(this).attr("href");
    $(t_content).show('500');

    $('.bobs').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("current");
    $(t_content).hide('500');
    $('.bobs').show();
  }
  return false
});
```

```css
.social_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: chocolate;
}

.social_container>div {
  display: none
}

.social_icons>a.current {
  background: aqua;
}

.bobs {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="social_icons">
  <a href="#content1">Вкладка 1</a>
  <a href="#content2">Вкладка 2</a>
  <a href="#content3">Вкладка 3</a>

  <div class="social_container">
    <div id="content1">Содержимое 1</div>
    <div id="content2">Содержимое 2</div>
    <div id="content3">Содержимое 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bobs"></div>
```

Comment: Вы, все таки, не добавили полный код для воспроизведения проблемы с прокруткой. Возможно, именно в варианте с href можно было исправить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
$(".social_icons>a").click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
    var tab = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(".social_icons>a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");

    $(".social_container>div").hide();
    $(".social_container>div[data-id=" + tab + "]").show(500);

    $('.bobs').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("current");
    $(".social_container>div").hide();
    $('.bobs').show();
  }
  return false
});
```

```css
.social_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: chocolate;
}

.social_container>div {
  display: none
}

.social_icons>a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.social_icons>a.current {
  background: aqua;
}

.bobs {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="social_icons">
  <a data-id="content1">Вкладка 1</a>
  <a data-id="content2">Вкладка 2</a>
  <a data-id="content3">Вкладка 3</a>

  <div class="social_container">
    <div data-id="content1">Содержимое 1</div>
    <div data-id="content2">Содержимое 2</div>
    <div data-id="content3">Содержимое 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bobs"></div>
```